# backup postgresql database on seperate gear on openshift

Tags: postgresql, openshift, pg-dump

how do I back up my database from openshift in gz format, so that I can import it on my localhost postgres database? I used to use [this script](https://gist.github.com/skyebook/3407646):

```
NOW="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"
FILENAME="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/$OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME.$NOW.backup.sql.gz"
pg_dump $OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME | gzip > $FILENAME
```

and then import:

```
gunzip -c digrin27.2015-07-10.backup.sql.gz | psql digrin
```

If I run backup code `pq_dump DB_NAME` I get this error:
`pg_dump digrin`

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "digrin" failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.48321"?
```

So how do I backup my database that is on separate gear? I tried to download snapshot, but only files were downloaded.

Comment: You need to tell `pg_dump` what host to connect to over TCP/IP using the `-h` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, thanks Craig. Added host made it work.

```
pg_dump $OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME -h $OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST | gzip > $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/$OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME.$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").backup.sql.gz`
```